# How do I create a jar in Gradle while keeping applicationDefaultJvmArgs path not null?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, executable-jar

I can't figure out this issue. How do I create a jar file in Gradle that will have non-null applicationDefaultJvmArgs?

In my java program I have the following String variable I need for my config file:

```
String CONFIG_PATH = "config.dir";
String configFilePath = System.getProperty(CONFIG_PATH);
```

I have the following build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'distribution'

version 1.0
mainClassName = 'app.service.AppMain'

def projectDir = file("src/main/java")
def configDir = file("src/main/config")
def resourceDir = file("src/main/resources")

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Dconfig.dir=${configDir}", "-Dresources.dir=${resourceDir}"]

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir projectDir
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs configDir, resourceDir
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
...
}

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            into('') {
                from { fileTree(configDir) }
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories    {
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  def installDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/lib"  
  def d = new File (installDir)
  if ( d.exists() ) {
      flatDir { dirs installDir }
    } else {
      mavenCentral()
  }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Implementation-Version": "$version",
                   "Main-Class": "$mainClassName")
    }
   doFirst {
        from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } } 
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA' 
}

// Augments the run task to add arguments
// e.g.  gradle run -PappArgs=--list
run {
    if (project.hasProperty("appArgs")) {
        args(appArgs.split(','))
    }
}
```

After building, when I run the **./app** executable from the **app/build/distributions/app/bin/** directory the configFilePath string is printed correctly as **/home/user/app/src/main/config**.

However, when I go to the **app/build/libs** dir and run **java -jar app-1.0.jar** I get **null** for my configFilePath. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer : you can't, `jar` can't hold jvm args.

`applicationDefaultJvmArgs` is a property from the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html). It has no effect on the regular built jar.

You can't include jvm args in a jar, the `java` binary takes them directly as parameters. So either you stick with the generated executable provided by the `application` plugin, or you hard code it (but i don't think you will)

Comment: That's unfortunate, thanks for the helpful explanation!